# WPF XAML Animate/blinking a button on mouse over

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, storyboard

I have a custom message box with two button 'Yes' and 'No'. Button 'Yes' is green and button 'No' is red.

I apply the same style for the two buttons through a xaml file defined separately as below:

**MsgBoxButtonStyle.xaml**:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="Button" 

x:Key="MsgBoxButtonStyle">
        <Setter Property="Background" 

        Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" 

        Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border  Name="Border" CornerRadius="0"  

                    BorderBrush="#000" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 

                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" 

                        ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 

                        Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 

                        HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" 

                        Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 

                        VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

These two buttons are place in my WPF window as below:

```
<Window x:Class="My.XAML.Controls.Windows.WpfMessageBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation">

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary  Source="/My.XAML;component/Styles/MsgBoxButtonStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources> 

   <Button Name="btnYes" Content="Yes"                             
            Click="Button_Click" Foreground="Black" 
            Style="{StaticResource MsgBoxButtonStyle}"    
            Background="#b6dbd6" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

    <Button Name="btnNo" Content="No"                             
            Click="Button_Click" Foreground="Black" 
            Style="{StaticResource MsgBoxButtonStyle}"
            Background="#dbb6b6" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
</Window>
```

Now, I would like to perform a nice effect when mouse is positioned over the buttons,  some kind of blinking or whatever using storyboard and dependant on the color of the button.

Also I would like to put this storyboard within my existing style file MsgBoxButtonStyle.xaml and no put each storyboard in the window for each button, i want to share it.

How can I do this? some one can provide me a nice effect for buttons?

Comment: You mentioned storyboard, seems you know where to start. Where do you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add triggers to the style. Here's an example to start you off.

```
 <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="120" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="120" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ThicknessAnimation Duration="0:0:0.250" To="0" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" />
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.550" To="100" 
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </Trigger.ExitActions>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: ok it works. buttons are resized when mouse hover/over and also when on button leave but problem with this effect is that window where button are contained also is resized if button are close to bottom right corner. Anyway I accept your answer.